# Variable interpolation in procedures postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables, string-interpolation

In psql, I can do:

```
\set foo 'id'
select * from table order by :"foo" desc;
```

But I cannot seem to do the same for function parameter variables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example(
        order_by VARCHAR
)
        LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
BEGIN
                SELECT 
                        id  
                FROM 
                        table
                ORDER BY :"order_by" DESC
...
```

I get a syntax error instead.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for that. Variables can't be used for identifiers.